# Spring Boot & MySql - cannot use a new service database username / password

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, docker, jenkins

How can I change the database user password so that the Spring Boot application can still use the database? The environment is Docker and Jenkins.

Changing the password from 'password1' to 'password2' does not work. The Sprint Boot application fails to connect to the (MySql) database. The error is: cannot connect due to invalid user credentials.

My environment consists of:

1 - My docker-compose.yml I have:

```
services:
  xyzdb:
    image: mysql:8.0.12
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=admin
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=geosoldatabase
      - MYSQL_USER=johan
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=${LOCAL_MYSQL_PASSWORD}
    volumes:
      - /var/mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
Etc.
```

2 - The Spring Boot apllication.properties file contains:

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://xyxdb:3306/geosoldatabase
spring.datasource.username = johan
spring.datasource.password = bladiebladiebla  <== very first password
```

3 - To change the password I did the following actions:

- Changed the user password by entering the database docker container and change the name with:

> ```
> ALTER USER 'johan'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'xyzabc123';
> ALTER USER 'johan' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'xyzabc123';
> Commit; 
> flush privileges;
> ```

- Updated 2 environment variables in my Jenkins System environment

> ```
> LOCAL_MYSQL_PASSWORD=xyzabc123
> SPRING.DATASOURCE.PASSWORD=xyzabc123
> ```

This does not work. Starting the Spring Boot application (after rebooting Jenkins) fails on not being able to connect to the database with the user name. There is a wrong password.

When I change all 3 updates (in the above 2 points) back to the initial password, then everything works fine.

What did I forget?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For months, no solution was suggested. That's a signal.

Since a few months I work with a Dockerized version of MySQL. That works fine. No issues yet.

The 'good' workaround is by using MySQL via Docker.